# Three-points projection JS

Tags: javascript, vector, projection, orthographic, vanishing-point

I have a 2 points projection sketch based on two lines intersection algorithms.
For example, if there's a 3D point `{ x: -4, y: 2, z: -2 }` and axes origin is pre-defined, I could find `a = {x: -4, y: 2, z: 0}` and `b = {x: 0, y: 2, z: -2}` points and find one possible intersection of line `{vanishingPointX, a)` and another line of `{vanishingPointZ, b)` and as you can see the code works fine.

[image]

And the task is to add another 3-rd point, so the output should like this:

[image]

> it's a rough illustration, some lines are distorted.

I have tried to project Y values along X-axis, but anyway neither there's no algorithm of three lines intersection nor these three lines don't intersect together at one point.

And the last but not least, I am aware that this problem could be solved with matrices, however, I'm trying to do it calculus-free.

```js
const scale = 64.0;
const far = 6.0;

const cube = [

  { x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0 },
  { x: 1.0, y: -1.0, z: 1.0 },
  { x: -1.0, y: -1.0, z: 1.0 },
  { x: -1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0 },
  { x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: -1.0 },
  { x: 1.0, y: -1.0, z: -1.0 },
  { x: -1.0, y: -1.0, z: -1.0 },
  { x: -1.0, y: 1.0, z: -1.0 },

];

const sides = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 4, 0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7];

let vanishingPointZ = { x: -3.5, y: 2.0 };
let vanishingPointX = { x: 5.0, y: 2.0 };
let vanishingPointY = { x: 0.0, y: -6.0 };

let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let zero = { x: canvas.width / 2, y: canvas.height / 2 };

draw();

function draw(){

    ctx.font = '32px serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0"
    ctx.fillText('X', zero.x + vanishingPointX.x * scale + 16, zero.y + vanishingPointX.y * scale + 16);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F0F";
    ctx.fillText('Y', zero.x + vanishingPointY.x * scale + 32, zero.y + vanishingPointY.y * scale + 16);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00F";
    ctx.fillText('Z', zero.x + vanishingPointZ.x * scale - 32, zero.y + vanishingPointZ.y * scale + 16);

    cube.forEach((p_, i_) =>{

        project(p_);

        let pos = { x: zero.x + p_.dx * scale, y: zero.y + p_.dy * scale };

        //to x
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(zero.x + vanishingPointX.x * scale, zero.y + vanishingPointX.y * scale);
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.33)";
        ctx.stroke();

        //to z
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(zero.x + vanishingPointZ.x * scale, zero.y + vanishingPointZ.y * scale);
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.33)";
        ctx.stroke();

        //to upper y
        //to x
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(zero.x + vanishingPointY.x * scale, zero.y + vanishingPointY.y * scale);
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.33)";
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#DEDEDE";
        ctx.fill();

    })

    for(let i = 0; i < sides.length; i += 2){

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(zero.x + cube[sides[i]].dx * scale, zero.y + cube[sides[i]].dy * scale);
        ctx.lineTo(zero.x + cube[sides[i + 1]].dx * scale, zero.y + cube[sides[i + 1]].dy * scale);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
        ctx.stroke();

    }

}

function project(p_){

  let distX = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vanishingPointX.x, 2), Math.pow(vanishingPointX.y - p_.y, 2));
  let vx = { x: vanishingPointX.x, y: vanishingPointX.y - p_.y };

  let nx = Math.exp( p_.x / far );

  vx.x *= nx;
  vx.y *= nx;

  let x = { x: vanishingPointX.x - vx.x, y: vanishingPointX.y - vx.y };

  let distZ = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vanishingPointZ.x, 2), Math.pow(vanishingPointZ.y - p_.y, 2));
  let vz = { x: vanishingPointZ.x, y: vanishingPointZ.y - p_.y };

  let nz = Math.exp( p_.z / far );

  vz.x *= nz;
  vz.y *= nz;

  let z = { x: vanishingPointZ.x - vz.x, y: vanishingPointZ.y - vz.y };

  let out =  twoLinesIntersection(vanishingPointZ, z, vanishingPointX, x);

  //trying to calculate y projection and it seems that as standalone it work fine

  let distY = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vanishingPointY.x, 2), Math.pow(vanishingPointX.y - p_.x, 2));
  let vy = { x: vanishingPointY.y, y: vanishingPointY.y - p_.x };

  let ny = Math.exp( p_.y / far );

  vy.x *= ny;
  vy.y *= ny;

  let y = { x: vanishingPointY.x - vy.x, y: vanishingPointY.y - vy.y };

  p_.dx = out.x;
  p_.dy = out.y;

}

function twoLinesIntersection(p1_, p4_, p3_, p2_){

    let d1 = (p1_.x - p2_.x) * (p3_.y - p4_.y);
    let d2 = (p1_.y - p2_.y) * (p3_.x - p4_.x);
    let d  = (d1) - (d2);

    let u1 = (p1_.x * p2_.y - p1_.y * p2_.x);
    let u4 = (p3_.x * p4_.y - p3_.y * p4_.x);

    let u2x = p3_.x - p4_.x;
    let u3x = p1_.x - p2_.x;
    let u2y = p3_.y - p4_.y;
    let u3y = p1_.y - p2_.y;

    return { x: (u1 * u2x - u3x * u4) / d, y: (u1 * u2y - u3y * u4) / d };

}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='800' height='800'></canvas>
```

Comment: This was a really good question, that a lot of people will benefit from having an answer to, so I requested it be undeleted in order to post an answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

We can make this easier to compute by, rather than adding vector compounds to a start coordinate until we're at the "real"  coordinate, treating the problem as one of line intersections. For example, if we want the point `XYZ = (1,2,2)` we can find it using line intersections by following this visual "recipe":

[image]

For any 3D point we can first compute the points on the YZ and XY planes, after which we can find the true point with one more line intersection. This does rely on knowing where on the screen our origin can be found (we could pick a point in the middle of the triangle Z-Y-X, but whatever screen point we pick, let's call that **C**, after which the code looks like this:

```js
function get(x, y, z) {
  if (x===0 && y===0 && z===0) return C;
    
  // Get the points at the distances along our Z and X axes:
  const px = lerp(C, X, perspectiveMap(x));
  const pz = lerp(C, Z, perspectiveMap(z));

  // If our 3D coordinate lies on the XZ plane, then this
  // is just a matter of finding the line/line intersection:
  if (y==0) return twoLinesIntersection(X, pz, Z, px);

  // If it's not, we construct the two points on the YZ and XY planes:
  const py = lerp(C, Y, perspectiveMap(y));
  const YZ = twoLinesIntersection(Y, pz, Z, py);
  const XY = twoLinesIntersection(Y, px, X, py);

  // And then the 3D coordinate is a line/line intersection with those.
  return twoLinesIntersection(XY, Z, X, YZ);
}

function lerp(v1, v2, r) {
  const mr = 1 - r;
  return {
    x: v1.x * mr + v2.x * r,
    y: v1.y * mr + v2.y * r,
    z: v1.z * mr + v2.z * r,
  };
}
```

With the perspective mapping function turns a value on the axis into a distance ratio between the origin and the axis' vanishing point. What that function looks like is effectively up to you, but if we want straight lines to stay straight, we'll want a rational perspective function:

```js
const DEFAULT_PERSPECTIVE_STRENGTH = 0.3;

function perspectiveMap(value, strength=DEFAULT_PERSPECTIVE_STRENGTH) {
  return 1 - 1/(1 + value * strength);
}
```

(we computer "1 minus..." because as a ratio between the origin and a vanishing point, we want this value to be 0 at x/y/z=0, so that `lerp(origin, vanishingPoint, value)` yields the origin, and we want it to become 1 as x/y/z approach infinity. Just on its own, `1/(1+v*s)` does the exact opposite of that, so subtracting it from one "flips" it around)

Implemented as a snippet:

```js
const w = 600, h = 300;
perspective.width = w;
perspective.height = h;
const DEFAULT_PERSPECTIVE_STRENGTH = 0.2;
const ctx = perspective.getContext("2d");

// our vanishing points and origin
let Z = { x: w*0.05, y: h*0.85 };
let X = { x: w*0.92, y: h*0.95 };
let Y = { x: w*0.65, y: h*0.1 };
let C = { x: w*0.65, y: h*0.50 };

// draw our "grid" and labels
line(X,C);
line(Y,C);
line(Z,C);

ctx.strokeStyle = `#00000020`;
drawGrid(10);
ctx.fillStyle = `#400`;

text("X", X,  10, 0);
text("Z", Z, -10, 0);
text("Y", Y, 0, -5);

// draw a 2x2x2 cube

ctx.strokeStyle = `#000000`;
drawCube(2);

// ------------ functions for content ------------

function drawGrid(e) {
  for(let i=0; i<e; i++) {
    line(X, get(0,i,0));
    line(X, get(0,0,i));
    line(Y, get(i,0,0));
    line(Y, get(0,0,i));
    line(Z, get(i,0,0));
    line(Z, get(0,i,0));
  }  
}

function drawCube(n) {
  const cube = getCube(n);
  const [p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8] = cube.map(p => get(p));
  quad(p1,p2,p3,p4);
  quad(p5,p6,p7,p8);
  line(p1,p5);
  line(p2,p6);
  line(p3,p7);
  line(p4,p8);
}

function getCube(n) {
  return [
    {x: n, y: n, z: n},
    {x: 0, y: n, z: n},
    {x: 0, y: n, z: 0},
    {x: n, y: n, z: 0},
    {x: n, y: 0, z: n},
    {x: 0, y: 0, z: n},
    {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0},
    {x: n, y: 0, z: 0},
  ];
}

// ------------ some draw util functions ------------

function line(p1, p2) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
  ctx.stroke(); 
}

function quad(p1, p2, p3, p4) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
  ctx.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y);
  ctx.lineTo(p4.x, p4.y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke(); 
}

function text(str, point, ox=0, oy=0) {
  const { x, y } = point;
  ctx.fillText(str, x+ox, y+oy);
}

// ------------ and: our coordinate computer ------------

function get(x,y,z) {
  if (y === undefined) {
    z = x.z;
    y = x.y;
    x = x.x
  }

  if (x===0 && y===0 && z===0) return C;

  const px = lerp(C, X, map(x));
  const pz = lerp(C, Z, map(z));
  if (y==0) return lli(X, pz, Z, px);

  const py = lerp(C, Y, map(y));
  const YZ = lli(Y, pz, Z, py);
  const XY = lli(Y, px, X, py);
  return lli(XY, Z, X, YZ);
}

function lerp(v1, v2, r) {
  const mr = 1 - r;
  return {
    x: v1.x * mr + v2.x * r,
    y: v1.y * mr + v2.y * r,
    z: v1.z * mr + v2.z * r
   }
}

function lli(p1,p2,p3,p4) {
  return lli8(p1.x,p1.y,p2.x,p2.y,p3.x,p3.y,p4.x,p4.y);
}

function lli8(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4) {
  const d = (x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4);
  if (d === 0) return undefined;

  const f12 = (x1*y2 - y1*x2);
  const f34 = (x3*y4 - y3*x4);
  const nx = f12*(x3-x4) - (x1-x2)*f34;
  const ny = f12*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*f34;
  return { x: nx/d, y: ny/d };
}

function map(value, strength=DEFAULT_PERSPECTIVE_STRENGTH) {
  return 1 - 1/(1 + value*strength);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="perspective">
```